# Replacing outlet with GFCI where tab broke on existing outlet

Tags: electrical

Looking to add GF coverage under kitchen sink where the two outlets are for the dishwasher (also hot water dispenser) and the disposal (only thing plugged into that outlet). 2 gang box.  2 20 amp single poles in panel; one for DW and one for disposal.  12/2-2 cable from panel with home run to junction box for disposal switch and continues on to 2 gang. The outlet for the disposal has the tab broke so the other receptacle can be used for another device (without being dependent on the disposal switch) and is wired as such in the junction box.  **Question**: Is there a way for me to add GF coverage for the disposal outlet and keep existing setup (i.e. two separate circuits to DW and disposal and independent receptacles on disposal outlet)? I don't think a GFCI outlet will work (or at least "I" don't know). I can throw GFCI breakers on the panel but so far the advice from two electricians who are providing quotes to replace my split-bus panel is to install GFCI outlets (I forgot to mention the particular wiring on the one outlet at the time).  Since I don't know when I'm going to replace the panel and what type of panel/breakers when I do, prefer not to throw breakers in now. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: When you say 12/2-2 do you mean dual 12/2 runs, or literal "12/2/2" cable (which is a thing)?  Is the *neutral* tab broken on the receptacle?    Is the junction box under the sink surface mount (bump with sides accessible) or flush mount (embedded in the wall)?

Comment: @HarperThe latter, one red hot, one black hot, one white neutral, one candy striped neutral and one ground.  Initially thought I had another MWBC on my hands but...  Neutral tab intact.  Flush mount box.  Added pic to post (disposal outlet on right)

Comment: A GFCI receptacle can not replace a split receptacle unless you cap one of the splits. This is normally a switched one and a always hot you could cap the switched then the GFCI receptacle would work. If you want to keep a switched or other form of split receptacle then it is best done by replacing the circuit breaker with a gfci, other forms of splits are 2 circuits one on the top and a second on the bottom.

Comment: Thanks all.  What I assumed but hoping there was something I was missing.  I'm going to sit tight for now and wait for the other panel replacement quotes to come in, get a feeling for timeframe and then make a call.  Electricians in this area are extremely busy and are having issues getting parts (per them).